# upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5 causing "IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features.."

Tags: android, xml

I was running my app fine using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 but after updating to Canary 5 the app now crashes on start with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:474)  
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)  
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)  
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)  
at com.bleachr.fan_engine.activities.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:138)
```

I've narrowed it down to what I think is an issue loading the app styles..

the Exception mentions `windowNoTitle: false` when I'm setting this flag to `true`. Here's the relevant xml lines I can think of:

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

I'm not overriding the theme for this Activity in any other way so that should be it..

My initial thought is somehow the `windowNoTitle` isn't being loaded - otherwise it'd be logged as `true` in the Exception. Does that make sense?

Any thoughts? I'm not sure if/how I can downgrade to Canary 4 again.. I'm sure I can use the stable build but I'd rather figure out this issue if possible.

Update: I removed `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` from AndroidManifest and still getting the same Exception!

Note I've done the 'invalidate and restart' option in Android Studio as well as about everything else I've seen in other similar Stack Overflow posts.

Also - there's no v21/styles.xml or anything else that should be in the way here either in case you were wondering..

Comment: For now, I downgraded to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 and the app is working again.. no other changes aside from the 2 gradle tools changes that Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5 makes when you update

Comment: I've been getting this as well. Have you opened an issue on the gradle plugin/android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties`?
Removing it - solves the issue.

Looks like starting with Canary 5, aapt1 does not merge styles items properly. I've digged into `AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor` and `this.mWindowNoTitle` does not match value set for style with:
`<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

```
// AppCompatDelegateImplV9
private ViewGroup createSubDecor() {
    TypedArray a = this.mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(styleable.AppCompatTheme);

    // ~~~~ERROR:  false returned (ignoring value from xml)
    if(a.getBoolean(styleable.AppCompatTheme_windowNoTitle, false)) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(1);
    }
```

Did anyone raised an issue on issuetracker.google.com?

Comment: thanks - I'll give that a try! I have a comment in gradle.properties however that suggests it's needed for another library.. so I might be out of luck

`    # enableAapt2=false set to fix the following issue.. remove when issue is fixed:`
`    # -> https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form/issues/30`
`    android.enableAapt2=false`

Comment: I had it there due aapt issue with comma/dot in float numbers. But in my case there is another fix to bypass it and enable aapt2 back